# How call #template_params in a form

Tags: mediawiki

Using WikiMedia, I am trying to configure Templates and Forms following [this documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms/Quick_start_guide).
But I am facing an error.

Content of the Template :

```
<noinclude>
{{#template_params:}}
</noinclude><includeonly>
{{#template_display:_format=plain}}
[[Category:Ship]]
</includeonly>
```

Content of the Form :

```
<noinclude>
This is the "Ship" form.
To create a page with this form, enter the page name below;
if a page with that name already exists, you will be sent to a form to edit that page.

{{#forminput:form=Ship}}

</noinclude><includeonly>
<div id="wikiPreview" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"></div>
{{{for template|Ship}}}
{| class="formtable"
|}
{{{end template}}}
</includeonly>
```

Content of an instance :

```
{{Ship}}
```

This produce the following error :

**Error: #template_params must be called in the template "Ship".**

I was not able to find ressource on this error. Can anyone have a hint at least ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I was not able *to call #template_params in a form*, but I was able to get rid of this error simply by deleting both `#template_params` and `#template_display`.

Content of the Template :

```
<noinclude>
</noinclude><includeonly>
[[Category:Ship]]
</includeonly>
```

Content of the Form :

```
<noinclude>
This is the "Ship" form.
To create a page with this form, enter the page name below;
if a page with that name already exists, you will be sent to a form to edit that page.

{{#forminput:form=Ship}}

</noinclude><includeonly>
<div id="wikiPreview" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"></div>
{{{for template|Ship}}}
{| class="formtable"
|}
{{{end template}}}
</includeonly>
```